# how to get filtered dataset from Datatable using LINQ

Tags: asp.net, webforms

i have a data table that contains employees data, this data is bind to Grid view. i have header drop downs for country, rank, section in grid view. whenever a selected drop down index changes, i use LINQ to get data as per Say country drop down and save it in **Viewstate** for further Filtering operations. this works fine.

i am saving the filter values in dictionary, say DictionaryFilters,  if no filter is set, the value of key is set to ALL.

for instance i choose, country and then section. the filtered data is fine. but if i set country back to all, section filter still exists. since i have 4-5 filtering drop downs in my grid, how is it possible to query data from data table by using only one LINQ query and by using Dictionary values rather than multiple conditional queries. is there any % for selecting column, so that i change ALL in dictionary value to this specific operator?

```
filter["Country"]="UK"; filter["Section"]="HR"; filter["rank"]="All";



 var query = from a in datatable
                        where a.Field<string>("Country")filter["Country"] &&
                              a.Field<string>("Section")==filter["Section"] &&
                              a.Field<string>("Rank")==filter["rank"] 
                        select a;
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to test if your filter value is set to "All" before filtering? It would be something like:

```
(filter["Country"] == "All") || (a.Field<string>("Country")filter["Country"])
```

This way, when the `filter["Country"]` is set to "All", the `or` operator don't evaluate the second statement (it's called short-circuit operator).

Hope it helps!